# How to set un-executable permission for the file in ntfs partition in linux?

Tags: linux, partitioning, permissions, ntfs, windows-10

Enter into debian whose filesystem is ext4:

```
vim /tmp/sphinx.rst

sphinx tutorial
=====================
installation
---------------
::

 sudo apt-get install python3-sphinx

create a new project
--------------------------
::

    mkdir  mydoc
    cd mydoc
    sphinx-quickstart
```

Display `sphinx.rst` permission:

```
ls -al   sphinx.rst
-rwxrwxrwx 1 debian debian 261 Aug 17 11:54 sphinx.rst
```

It can be executed when to input the absolute path `/tmp/sphinx.rst`.

```
/tmp/sphinx.rst
/tmp/sphinx.rst: line 1: sphinx: command not found
/tmp/sphinx.rst: line 2: ====================================================================: command not found
/tmp/sphinx.rst: line 3: installation: command not found
/tmp/sphinx.rst: line 4: ---------------: command not found
/tmp/sphinx.rst: line 5: ::: command not found
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  python-babel-localedata python3-alabaster python3-babel python3-imagesize
  python3-jinja2 python3-markupsafe sphinx-common
Suggested packages:
  python-jinja2-doc python3-sphinx-rtd-theme dvipng sphinx-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python-babel-localedata python3-alabaster python3-babel python3-imagesize
  python3-jinja2 python3-markupsafe python3-sphinx sphinx-common
0 upgraded, 8 newly installed, 0 to remove and 46 not upgraded.
Need to get 4,408 kB of archives.
After this operation, 23.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Change its permission as `644`, it can be executed.

```
sudo chmod 644  sphinx.rst
/tmp/sphinx.rst
bash: /tmp/sphinx.rst: Permission denied
```

`sdb2` is in `ntfs` format.

```
sudo blkid |grep sdb2
/dev/sdb2: LABEL="winntfs" UUID="284A29774A2942C4" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="292c184b-766f-4036-8fa0-5bcd936b85c2"
```

Mount it with `/mnt/winntfs`:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb2  /mnt/winntfs
```

Copy `/tmp/sphinx.rst` in `ext4` partition into `ntfs` partition.

```
cp /tmp/sphinx.rst /mnt/winntfs
ls -al  /mnt/winntfs/sphinx.rst
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 261 Aug 17 12:02 /mnt/winntfs/sphinx.rst
sudo chmod 644 /mnt/winntfs/sphinx.rst
ls -al  /mnt/winntfs/sphinx.rst
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 261 Aug 17 12:02 /mnt/winntfs/sphinx.rst
```

I can't revise file's mode in my debian, now reboot and enter into win10,set its permission as `read and write`, containing no `execute`.

[image]

Reboot and re-enter into debian, re-mount `dev/sdb2`,`/mnt/winntfs/sphinx.rst` still can be executed, how to set un-executable  permission for the file `sphinx.rst` in ntfs partition in linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the ntfs-3g driver ignores the actual NTFS permissions and always shows fixed values (like the vfat driver). You can change those using the mount options `fmask=0133`, `uid=1000`, etc.

To activate full chown/chmod support, you need to mount with the option `-o permissions` or to create a valid .NTFS-3G/UserMapping file.

Comment: Both `mount` and `ntfs-3g` command contains no argument `file_mode=` in `man mount` and `man ntfs-3g`.

Comment: Ah, right, I confused it with CIFS – it's `fmask`/`dmask` in ntfs-3g.

Answer (score 0):

Both `mount` and `ntfs-3g` command contains no argument `file_mode=` in `man mount` and `man ntfs-3g`.

```
sudo mount -o permissions /dev/sdb2  /mnt/winntfs
```

or

```
sudo ntfs-3g -o permissions /dev/sdb2  /mnt/winntfs
```

They take same effect,then you can set file mode with `sudo chmod 644 /mnt/winntfs/sphinx.rst`,it can't execute.